# Выборка по числу с БД

Tags: выборка, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Нужно сделать выборку по числу с БД.

Сразу скажу поле находится дата имеет формат не date, а int.

Все записывается с функции time().

База данных имеет примерно такую структуру

```
id time
1  1394553008
2  1394553008  
3  1396553308
4  1324233008
...
```

Я попытался сделать такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE YEAR(time)='2014';
```

Результат получил, но такой то странный, в БД хранится около 100 записей, и все внесены были в этом году, но получил в результате их только 6

Так быть в таком случаи?

Comment: А я бы хранил в БД DATETIME а уже в коде если надо преоразовывал бы в  timestamp, тем более в php например для этого есть стандартные методы. Просто так вы не будете насиловать mysql при выборках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю оптимизирует ли mysql YEAR(time) вообще для надежности я бы сделал `WHERE time<UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015/01/01") AND time>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014/01/01");`

а так, YEAR он для типа datetime, поэтому надо YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) но что-то мне кажется это будет намного медленнее чем если посчитать сразу границы